# Using package locally

Tags: fonts, packages

Is there a way to use a package locally?

Here is the case...

I NEED to use `\phiup` on my document, however it needs the using of package `pxfonts` or `txfonts`. However, when I use either of those packages, it will make the whole documents uglier, u may try writing `\Vdash` on your document with and without those packages, and see the difference.

That's the point of my question. Can I use the package locally, or in this case, I want that `pxfonts` (or `txfonts`) package will be used only when I write `\phiup`, otherwise I just want to use the normal font.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about borrowing the definition of the symbol from `txfonts.sty`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%
\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersA}{U}{txmia}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phiup}{\mathord}{lettersA}{30}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\phi\quad\phiup
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

No, not in general. It is theoretically possible to write

```
\begingroup
\usepackage{foo}
\global\let\foocmd\foocmd % access this command only
\endgroup
```

But packages aren't designed to be loaded like that and it would rarely work correctly.

For upright greek, you can try the `upgreek` package; with the symbol fonts it'll match what you're seeing in the tx fonts; Palatino users should use its `Euler` option instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[Symbol]{upgreek}
\begin{document}
$\phi$ v $\upphi$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need the `\phiup`, not the `\Vdash`. I wrote the `\Vdash` just as example how things can go wrong when I use package `txfonts`

Comment: @zfm Oops, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: And `savesym` package is useful. See also the source code of 'The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List'.