# Designing medcirc and circledtimes symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, math-operators, amssymb

**It would be great**

1. to use only `\medcirc` and `\circledtimes` from the `pxfonts` or
2. **to design the similar symbols by other techniques**.

The symbols from `pxfonts` are quite well but when I connect the package, all symbols from the text are substituted by the symbols from `pxfonts`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pxfonts}

\begin{document}

1. Only medcirc and cirledtimes symbols are required from pxfonts: \par
 $\cdot^{\medcirc}$ and $\cdot^{\circledtimes}$.\par
2. The problem is that all symbols are substituted by pxfonts package,
 for example, just look at the text and formula $g(f)=a$.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

There are similar problems with `pxfonts`, but they seem to be unsolved. Perhaps, it's better to design the symbols by other ways.

[Use pxfonts in listings only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107627/use-pxfonts-in-listings-only)

[Using package locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11099/using-package-locally)

Comment: Don't put "please help me" in your question; it's redundant. (You obviously don't ask a question without wanting help to solve it.)

Comment: for the first part of the question, using only selected symbols, see [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use only those two symbols from `pxfonts` without loading it, add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{pxsyc}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsC}{bold}{U}{pxsyc}{bx}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{pxsyc}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medcirc}{\mathbin}{symbolsC}{7}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsZ}{OMS}{pxsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsZ}{bold}{OMS}{pxsy}{bx}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{OMS}{pxsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\circledtimes}{\mathbin}{symbolsZ}{10}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{pxfonts}

\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{pxsyc}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsC}{bold}{U}{pxsyc}{bx}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{pxsyc}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medcirc}{\mathbin}{symbolsC}{7}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsZ}{OMS}{pxsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsZ}{bold}{OMS}{pxsy}{bx}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{OMS}{pxsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\circledtimes}{\mathbin}{symbolsZ}{10}

\begin{document}

1. Only medcirc and cirledtimes symbols are required from pxfonts: \par
 $\cdot^{\medcirc}$ and $\cdot^{\circledtimes}$.\par
2. The problem is that all symbols are substituted by pxfonts package,
 for example, just look at the text and formula $g(f)=a$.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It seems to me that this code do smth with `\forall, \subseteq`, all `\mathcal{}` letters, http-links in the reference e.c.t.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko I know, I've edited the answer. Now it is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Since you specifically mention designing symbols using other techniques, here is an alternative.  I import Karl's accepted solution just to show the comparison of the two.

In the present solution, I use stacks to overlay glyphs, and I use the `scalerel` package to allow things to scale to the different math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{pxfonts}
%Karls import font solution, for comparison
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{pxsyc}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsC}{bold}{U}{pxsyc}{bx}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{pxsyc}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medcirc}{\mathbin}{symbolsC}{7}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsZ}{OMS}{pxsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsZ}{bold}{OMS}{pxsy}{bx}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{OMS}{pxsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\circledtimes}{\mathbin}{symbolsZ}{10}
%Current solution
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\mcirc{\scalebox{.7}{$\bigcirc$}}
\def\nmediumcircle{\kern-.1pt\mcirc\kern-6.9pt\mcirc}
\def\ntimesincircle{\mathbin{%
  \stackengine{-.74pt}{\nmediumcircle}{\scalebox{.96}{$\times$}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}
\def\mediumcircle{\mathbin{%
  \ThisStyle{\scalebox{.87}{$\SavedStyle\scalerel*{\nmediumcircle}{b}$}}}}
\def\timesincircle{\mathbin{%
  \ThisStyle{\scalebox{.87}{$\SavedStyle\scalerel*{\ntimesincircle}{b}$}}}}
\begin{document}
$x\medcirc\circledtimes
\scriptstyle\medcirc \circledtimes
\scriptscriptstyle\medcirc \circledtimes$
Karl's Solution

$x\mediumcircle\timesincircle
\scriptstyle\mediumcircle \timesincircle
\scriptscriptstyle\mediumcircle \timesincircle$
Present Solution
\end{document}
```

[image]